# Error "<istmt>: 3499 mm_radial() not found"

Tags: stata

I have installed in Stata 13.1 MP 64bit the `st0352` package, which performs propensity matching for continuous treatment variables and used the example provided by the authors.

Then i run the commands described by the author in the Stata Journal article but i got an error.

The code and results can be found below:

```
use "LotteryDataSet.dta", clear

drop if year6==.
su prize, de
drop if prize >= r(p95)
replace year6 = year6/1000
mat def tp = (10\20\30\40\50\60\70\80\90\100)

set more off

drf agew ownhs owncoll male tixbot workthen yearm1 yearm2 yearm3 yearm4 yearm5 yearm6, ///
outcome(year6) treatment(prize) gpscore(gps) test(L_like) tpoints(tp) numoverlap(3) ///
method(radialpspline) family(gaussian) link(log) nknots(7) det delta(1)

.................. omitted

****************
 DRF estimation 
****************

Radial penalized spline estimator

Run 1  ..                                   (Cpq =         716.46)
Run 2  ..                                   (Cpq =         583.26)
Run 3  ....                                 (Cpq =         594.32)
Run 4  ...                                  (Cpq =         639.28)
Run 5  ..                                   (Cpq =         601.10)

***<istmt>:  3499  mm_radial() not found***
```

I don't know why this is happening. I have searched Stata's official website but found nothing referring to `mm_radial()`.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `st0352` package refers to the `drf` *community-contributed command*, something which you fail to make clear in your question. It is customary and useful to provide this information right from the start, so others know that you do not refer to an official, built-in command.

In the remarks located in the help file of `drf`, the authors ask that you

> *"Please remember to use the update query command before running this program to make sure you have an up-to-date version of Stata installed. Otherwise, this program might not run properly..."*

Assuming you have done this ***before*** using the `drf` module and that the command has been installed correctly, then Stata probably does not know where to look to find the `mata` function `mm_radial()` and thus raises the error.

The aforementioned function should be contained in either `mata_drf_functions.mata` or `mata_spacefill_functions.mata`. These two files  should have been installed with the module.

In the Stata command prompt, type:

```
mata: mata mlib index
```

And try to run the command again.

---

**EDIT:**

I had a better look at this and it looks like you first need to create the `mata` library yourself.

So before you use the above command, you need to run the following:

```
clear all
findfile mata_drf_functions.mata
do "`r(fn)'"

findfile mata_spacefill_functions.mata
do "`r(fn)'"

mata: mata mlib create ldrf, dir(PLUS) replace
mata: mata mlib add ldrf *()
```

Comment: thanks for your kindly help, it helps a lot for me. i did send an email to the author of "moremata", Pr. Ben Jann because i found nothing with mm_radial() in moremata. your last edit posted did work, the error disappeared. I didn't expect to have the answer so quickly, I searched many places before I could find a solution. Thanks again!